# Use onActivityResult to call a function

Tags: java, android

I have an `PopUpActivity` which pops up a window and i'm very satisfied with that.

However, I want to be able to return information from the popup window back to the parent activity, but also be able to call a function on the parent activity once the popup window is closed. Could someone help me?

Here is my code in the `PopUpActivity`:

```
public void closePopUpAndSendResultBack(){ // and how can i pass data to the previous activity?
    //https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("data", "yo");
    //startActivityForResult(data, 1);  // gives me the error : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { (has extras) }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();

}
```

and here is my parent(MainActivity) function that I want to get called once the popUpWindow is closed:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            nameTextField.setText(""); // how can i get Yo inside here?
            showTheButton(); // and how can this function get called?

        }

    }
}}
```

Also, here is how I make that window Pop up from my Mainactivity:

```
     theOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent pop_up_that_window = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopActivity.class);
            pop_up_that_window.putExtra("first", "Velkommen du der!");
            startActivity(pop_up_that_window);

        }
    });


 }
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity use:

```
theOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent pop_up_that_window = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopActivity.class);
        pop_up_that_window.putExtra("first", "Velkommen du der!");
        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(pop_up_that_window, 1);

    }
});
```

And still in MainActivity in onActivityResult() use this code:

```
String yo = data.getStringExtra("data")
nameTextField.setText(yo);
```

Comment: you have to also startActivityForResult(), do you use it?

Comment: I uncommented the line, now it still gives me the same error:

  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { (has extras) }

Comment: you have to add your pop up activity to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: My popUpactivity is already added to the manifest and it works both opening and closing it. So the problem is not here?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem so you shouldn't uncomment this startActivityForResult() in popup activity, but in MainActivity launch PopupActivity with startActvityForResult() method.

Comment: What do you mean by "launch PopupActivity with startActvityForResult() method" ?

Comment: could you show code how you start popup activity in main activity?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question to show how the PopupWindow is activated from my MainActivity, also the code is here below:

     theOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent pop_up_that_window = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopActivity.class);
                pop_up_that_window.putExtra("first", "Velkommen du der!");
                startActivity(pop_up_that_window);

            }
        });


     }

Comment: startActivityForResult(pop_up_that_window);

Comment: and you want me to put this :  startActivityForResult(pop_up_that_window);  inside the protected void onActivityResult method?

Comment: "cannot resolve method startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent)" is the error message i get

Comment: try MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(pop_up_that_window); I updated the asnwer for better udnerstanding

Comment: Your answer did now work but i solved it using this:

startActivityForResult(pop_up_that_window, 1);

now it works perfectly! Thanks anyway.

Comment: ow yeah, i forgot about request code, if I helped please mark my answer with check mark. Regards